# Focused content extraction from html page

Tags: parsing, apache-tika

From a HTML page, how can I configure TIKA to get content only from a particular div. For eg:

```
  <div id="1" class="content">...</div>
  <div id="2" class="content">...</div>
  <div id="3" class="new_content">...</div>
```

I would like to know how to get content for div id="1" and class = "new_content"

Comment: In jquery / Javascript ?

Comment: This is very clearly NOT related to jQuery / javascript. Why did you edit the tags before receiving clarification if you were unsure?

Comment: not sure how the jquery tags got added. removed the irrelevant tags.

Comment: How are you calling Apache Tika? App? Server? Java? Java Facade? OSGi?